# How can I switch accounts on Gmail while the browser is not at full size?

Tags: google-chrome, email, gmail, user-interface

When I use Gmail, one annoying feature is that while the browser is at half size, I can't reach the account button to allow me to switch between my email accounts. I have to maximise the window to do this. Is there any workaround for this, such as a keyboard shortcut, or are there any fixes to gmail's UI that makes the gmail buttons scale with browser size, or at least add in a horizontal scrollbar, like most other websites?

This is what my browser looks like when I've got gmail on half-size. The switch account button is next to the 9-square-grid on the top-right-hand side, but it's not accessible, and I can't scroll to it.

[image]

Comment: what size screen & device are you using? This isnt normal.

Comment: Windows 10, Google Chrome browser, and according to some website, my display size is 1366 x 768.

Answer (score 3):

You can just change the address bar to your `user number`.

This is the default URL when signed in under your main account:
`https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox`

If you hover over your different accounts, you will see that URL changes the number `0` above to a `1`, `2`, `3`, etc depending on what account is in the list.

For example, I could change the Url from:

`https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox`  to
`https://mail.google.com/mail/u/2/#inbox`

and I would get my third account, or 2nd in the list.

Comment: Wow, I actually never knew that. That's so useful - I always wanted a way to go straight onto my uni email without having to navigate to my default email first!

Answer (score 1):

One limited "workaround" I can think of is just minimizing the page itself with `Ctrl`+`-` until the button become accessible.

Another possible workaround is to try to press `Tab` several times until the page scrolls itself right a bit because of some link being selected in the invisible right side of the page.

Comment: This does work, so I'm upvoting the answer. I'm just holding out for a UI fix. I really dislike Gmail's UI anyway.